Arithmetic Formatter Project- not giving me the solution in a horizontal line but on a new line

def arithmetic_arranger(problems, show_answers=False):
    #error handling:problems greater than 5

    if len(problems) > 5:
        return 'Error: Too many problems.'

    #splitting problems between operator and numbers
    split_problems = ''

    for problem in problems:           
        numberA, operator, numberB= problem.split()


    #error handling of problems- only digits allowed

        if not (numberA.isdigit() and numberB.isdigit()):
           return 'Error: Numbers must only contain digits.'

    #error handling of problems-no more than 4 digits 

        if len(numberA) > 4 or len(numberB) > 4:
           return 'Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits.'

    # Error handling of problems- incorrect operator 
        if operator not in ('+', '-'):
           return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."

    #define needed width

        width = max(len(numberA), len(numberB)) + 2
 
    #arranging the sums

        split_problems += numberA.rjust(width) + '\n'
        split_problems += operator + numberB.rjust(width - 1) + '\n'
        split_problems += '-' * width + '\n'

    return split_problems

print(f'\n{arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])}')

For the code above, I'm not too sure how to show the solution in a horizontal line since my solution at the moment is one answer below the other instead of next to each other.
You don't need to show me the solution just please explain what I can do to have it in a horizontal line next to each other than below each other.
I'm getting:
xxx
+xx
___
xxx
-xx
___
xxx
+xx
___
xxx
+xx
___


instead of:
none
xxx   (four spaces) another here  (four spaces) another here (four spaces) another here 
+xx
___

All indentations are accurate - I just couldn't do that here.

Please clean up all the your text in your posted code.

I fixed those up, but there are still some indentation problems. Please repost the code with proper indentation.

I don't understand the description of the desired output; what exactly does another here mean?  Another what?  Can you show the actual desired output, and not a description?

Hi Scott, I mean another of the arithmetic solution in the desire format... which is next to each other than below each other

If you want the output all in one line, why are you appending newline at various intervals?

@NolwaziMbatha have you checked the answers ? any matching your neeeds ?

You can separately handle the 3 lines and add 4 blank spaces each time.
At the end concat the 3 libes with '' separator, then display the string.
You can update your code this way:
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, show_answers=False):
    #error handling:problems greater than 5

    if len(problems) > 5:
        return 'Error: Too many problems.'

    #splitting problems between operator and numbers
    split_problems1 = ''
    split_problems2 = ''
    split_problems3 = ''

    for problem in problems:           
        numberA, operator, numberB= problem.split()


    #error handling of problems- only digits allowed

        if not (numberA.isdigit() and numberB.isdigit()):
           return 'Error: Numbers must only contain digits.'

    #error handling of problems-no more than 4 digits 

        if len(numberA) > 4 or len(numberB) > 4:
           return 'Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits.'

    # Error handling of problems- incorrect operator 
        if operator not in ('+', '-'):
           return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."

    #define needed width

        width = max(len(numberA), len(numberB)) + 2
        spacer = 4
 
    #arranging the sums

        split_problems1 += numberA.rjust(width) + ' '*spacer
        split_problems2 += operator + numberB.rjust(width - 1) +' '*spacer
        split_problems3 += '-' * width + ' '*spacer

    split_problems1 += '\n'
    split_problems2 += '\n'
    split_problems3 += '\n'

    split_problems = split_problems1 + split_problems2 + split_problems3

    return split_problems

print(f'\n{arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])}')

The result is:
   32      3801      45      123    
+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49    
-----    ------    ----    -----    


To do this, you would need to take all of your first numbers and put them in a list. Then, use a for loop and do something like this:
printstr = ""
for v, i in enumerate(numbers):
    if not v == len(numbers) - 1:
        printstr = printstr + f"{i}\t"
    else:
        printstr = printstr + f"{i}"

Then, you can print printstr and repeat the process for the rest of the numbers. (also, you can add a system that does the same thing for the lines that separate the equation and answer)

If numbers is not an empty list, printstr will always have a trailing tab character. Are you sure that's right?

Thanks for telling me, just corrected.
